# Webview shouldOverrideUrlLoading not catching URL requests

Tags: android, caching, webview, android-webview, webviewclient

I am trying to parse every click event, intercept the http url that attempts to load into the webview, and decide if it should be shown depending on a set of logic as per how the url parses. I have followed the advice on these 3 StackOverflow links:

1) [Intercept and override HTTP requests from WebView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4780899/intercept-and-override-http-requests-from-webview)

2) [Android Web-View shouldOverrideUrlLoading() Deprecated.(Alternative)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41972463/android-web-view-shouldoverrideurlloading-deprecated-alternative)

3) https://stackoverflow.com/a/32711309/2480714

without it fixing my issue. The main issue is that a user clicks on the webview to load a hyperlink and it is seems like the *shouldOverrideUrlLoading* method is not being called or is not intercepting the url properly every time.

I created my Custom WebViewClient and overrode it first with the intent of stopping all loads without my approval, but I have run into a snag; **some** urls are loading and bypassing my override methods and some are not. I have no clue why this is happening.

Here is my WebviewClient  class:

```
public class CustomWebViewClient2 extends WebViewClient {

    public CustomWebViewClient2(){

    }

    @Override
    public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
        Log.d("log", "(CustomWebViewClient) onPageFinished, URL == " + url);
    }


    @SuppressLint("NewApi")
    @Nullable
    @Override
    public WebResourceResponse shouldInterceptRequest(WebView view, WebResourceRequest request) {
        Log.d("log", "shouldInterceptRequest hit");
        return null;
    }

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public WebResourceResponse shouldInterceptRequest(WebView view, String url) {
        Log.d("log", "shouldInterceptRequest hit");
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, WebResourceRequest request) {
        Log.d("log", "(CustomWebViewClient) shouldOverrideUrlLoading");
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
        Log.d("log", "(CustomWebViewClient) shouldOverrideUrlLoading");
        return true;
    }


    @Override
    public void onLoadResource(WebView view, String url) {
        Log.d("log", "intercepting onLoadResource, url == " + url);
    }


    @Override
    public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url, Bitmap favicon) {
        Log.d("log", "onPageStarted url == " + url);
    }
}
```

As you can see, it is overriding the correct methods and should (in theory) **never** load a URL unless I pass it to the webview to load, but unfortunately some websites are loading, and others are not.

I also tried disabling the cache as per this comment in one of the answers:

> "A word of CAUTION! If you intercept an attempt by the browser to
>   retrieve an image (or probably any resource) and then return null
>   (meaning let the WebView continue retrieving the image), any future
>   requests to this resource might just go to the cache and will NOT
>   trigger shouldInterceptRequest(). If you want to intercept EVERY image
>   request, you need to disable the cache or (what I did) call
>   WebView.clearCache(true)"

but to no avail. Why are some URLs loading in and bypassing the override, but others are not?

**Update 1**: Here is a sample URL https://cookpad.com/us that mirrors the issue I am referring to. It seems to be related to Turbolinks being implemented on the server-side.